# AMD Software Host Application Pop-Up on startup

Tags: popup, amd

Whenever I start my PC AMD software host application pop-up appears.I have disabled it in the startup apps in task manager still it pop ups everytime I start my PC . Everytime I have to manually close the pop-up . User account control asks for permission every single time. Solution?

AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics

[Pop-Up Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7eoV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with the AMD Software: Host Application popup on startup with a Radeon 6800. The UAC tries to protect you but I was unable to find a solution until I came across the video [How To Fix Error Do you Want to allow this app to make Change to your device in Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stHkk_Bl6j4).

My solution was disabling the UAC for the “Adrenaline Software: Adrenaline Edition” that runs on startup.

Comment: But if i disable the UAC to never notify then it will affect all the existing softwares. Is it safe?

Comment: thanks for your help . I just want to know that is it safe if I disable UAC to "never notify" and will it affect my PC?